# Nservicebus Message stuck and not being processed or Handle

Tags: message-queue, nservicebus, msmq

We have two ASP.net web applications integrated with nservicebus with following configuration
App 1 is running nuservicebus v4 and App 2 is running nservicebus v3.

When I send the message from app 1 to app 2 it works fine and get processed. While when I send the message from app 2 to app 1 message gets delivered to messaging queue but doesn't get processed until I restart the app 1 from IIS.

my app.configs are as followed.

App-1

```html
<configSections>
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
 <section name="TransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.TransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />       
 <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
</configSections>

  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
  <TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel="5" MaxRetries="2" MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond="0"/>
   <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="AssemblyName" Endpoint="EndPoint@MachineName"/>
   </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

App-2

```html
<configSections>
<section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>
  
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
  <MsmqTransportConfig NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="AssemblyName" Endpoint="EndPoint@machineName"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Could you please advise? Thanks.

Comment: I really can't say much from this, it's too little information. Besides the fact that config has been 'obfuscated' and assembly names and endpoint & machine names have been taken out. Only thing I do see is that `MaximumMessageThroughputPerSecond` is set to 0. I doubt that will actually work, but perhaps we've never tested it for anyone to set it at 0.

Comment: Sounds like the app pool for app 2 is going to sleep.